# Docker containers in different directories under one daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am setting docker on cloud machine with two drives: HA slow drive and attached SSD fast drive. I would like to split containers between these two drives. I'd like to put IO-intensive containers on SSD drive and less IO-intensive on the HA drive.

I know it is possible to change location of all containers with `-g` daemon flag.

Is it possible to change location per container (preferably using `docker-compose`)?

Comment: I think you might need a combination of --device and --cap-add flags in docker run, but I've never tried this myself. These are easily translatable to compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simpler approach is to define volumes inside the SSD. In general IO-intensive operations should be in a volume, just create this volume in the SSD with docker-compose.

Regards